# What is the css positioning style that keeps all elements positioned the same when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css

My html page has some text, a search bar, a results pane, a navigation bar, and several other elements which i want to stay in the same position relative to each other.

My thoughts were to make absolutely positioned divs inside a relatively positioned container div, and then give them all min/max pixel values.

If i gave them min/max pixel values they wouldnt change size/positioning when the window was resized, correct?

But if i did this then wouldnt they not fit on monitors with smaller screens?

Forgive any inaccuracies in my statements, im still in the learning process.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not typically used for general positioning of elements because it removes the element from the normal flow of the document.  You're going to need a little more information here as to what you're trying to accomplish or risk having the question locked for being too vague.

Comment: Yeah, this is far too vague. This kind of thing doesn't work on a problem/solution basis; you have to learn all of how CSS positioning works to use it effectively (if at all). Get Googling, but stay away from W3Schools when learning this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the height and width to a percent, then set a min-height and min-width, the divs will flex to the size of the parent div (which is dependent on the size of the parent window).    The problem with that solution is that with smaller screen size windows, the absolute positioning for the elements won't allow you them to nudge down if the content of an individual div needs to wrap. You might be able to position your internal divs using the default browser settings and adjusting the margin values, and use float: left or float: right to position elements that need to be adjacent.